# Script to find IIS errors from multiple servers for a particular date

Tags: iis-7.5

I need to pull 500 errors from multiple servers and paste the 500 errors output to a text file using script

I am able to do it for a single server using batch script.

I am not specific for it to be in batch, any script is fine powershell, vbscript etc..

Comment: @echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"

set "today=%YY%%MM%%DD%"

findstr /i /c:"500 0 0" "\\sw10hs6784\IISLogs\W3SVC1\*%today%*.log" > "E:\outputs\output500.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You could use Log Parser for that as long as the folders are accessible over a network.

One simple way is to create a file say "file-shares.txt" where you paste the directories where your log files exist, something like:
c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\
C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC3\

And then simply run the following command line to get all the errors into errors.txt:

```
for /F %i in (shares.txt) do call logparser.exe -i:w3c "select * from %i\*.log where sc-status=500" -o:csv -q:on >> errors.txt
```

Comment: My requirement is as below:

Comment: Thanks Carlos.I will try with log parser. My requirement is as below: I have a text file which has a list of server names and a batch script that takes arguments as the text file that contains server names. The script needs to run remotely i.e, without logging into the server. Suppose a,b,c,d are server names, I will be running the script on z server, the script on z server must remotely check for IIS logs under E:\IISLogs\W3SVC1\*.log for each of the server name listed in servernames.txt file and if there is a 500 0 0 error found in the log, it must write the same to a notepad or a csv file.